# In sqlite3, how to insert "0" in a column when no value is found?

Tags: python, selenium, sqlite

I am using python/selenium to extract two phone numbers and then save the results to a  sqlite3 database. On some pages there is only one phone number, when this happens I get this error:-

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: table IRELAND has 7 columns but 6 values were supplied
```

The table has two columns for storing phone numbers PHONE1 CHAR(20), PHONE2 CHAR(20).

Is it possible to insert a 0 (Zero) when no value is found?

My Code :-

```
phones = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("phone")
for phone in phones:
    print phone.text
    query += ",\'"+phone.text+"\'"
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Use query parameters! Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
phones = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("phone")
for i in range(0,2):
    print phones[1]
    if phones[i]:
       query += ",\'"+phones[i].text+"\'"
    else:
       query += ",\'0\'"
```

Comment: I am getting an error print phone[1] NameError: name 'phone' is not defined

Comment: Check now. that is because phone field does not exist. I have modified the code.